# Jquery close popup dialog window on cancel without submitting the underlying form

Tags: jquery

I have a script that produces a modal popup dialog windows. The popup has two buttons, "Cancel" and "Login" and a feild for a user id to be entered. If I enter a user id and then click on the cancel button the underlying form is submitted when I need it to just cancel without submission. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

The script:

```
$(function() {
$("#LoginForm").attr('title', 'Login').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    width: 350,
    height: 300,
});

$( ".opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#LoginForm" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
});

$("#dologin").click(function() {
    $("#LoginForm").submit();
    $("#dologin").css("border","1px solid black");
});

function myfunction() {
    $("#close_login").dialog("close");
}

$('#LoginForm').click('shown.modal', function () {
$("#password").focus();
})
});
```

The form:

```
<div id="LoginBox" title="Login">
<form method = "post" action = "clear_faults_submit.php" target="_self" id="LoginForm" name="form1">
<div id="LoginAdminPINDiv">
<div class="PINFormSubHeaderBold">Enter Admin PIN:</div>
<div class="PINFormSubHeaderPass">
  <input type = "password" id = "password" name = "password" placeholder = "***" class="LoginInputBox" maxlength="4">
</div>
</div>
<div class="feedback" id="feedback"></div>
<div class="Clear">
<div id="divider"> </div>
</div>
<div id="LoginButtonsDiv">
<div id="CancelButtonsDiv">
  <input type = "image" id = "close_login" src = "images/cancel.png">
</div>
<div id="SubmitButtonsDiv">
  <input type = "image" id = "dologin" src = "images/login.png">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use toggle when cancel button is clicked
to prevent form submission use preventDefault.

```
 e.preventDefault();                              
 $('#LoginForm').toggle();
```

Comment: Hi and many thanks for your help. I changed the close function to :$("#close_login").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                              
   $('#LoginForm').toggle();
  $("#LoginForm").dialog("close");
    });. Perfect.

Comment: thats fine , i think now you don't need to close dialog. toggle does this for you.